# Having Trouble With UITextField and NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have the following code for `UITextField`.  The problem I'm having is that the text does not persist.  For example, when I present a modal view, then dismiss it, the `UITextField` does not have the text anymore in it.  I want the text to remain there until I dimiss that view with the text field.

I am displaying the `UITextField` like this:

```
UITextField *nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
nameTextField.delegate = self;
[nameTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingEnded) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
[nameTextField setEnabled: YES];
self.myTextField = nameTextField;
[nameTextField release];
```

Then I have:

```
- (void)editingEnded
{
    NSString *tempRoutineName = self.myTextField.text;
    self.routineName = tempRoutineName;
    [tempRoutineName release];
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of editingEnded, Implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. Go to the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method and reassign the value of text in it.

Like,

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if (textField.tag ==0){
    self.myTextField = textField; 

  // myTextField is a property
    }
```

Now in the in the `viewDidLoad` method or the `viewWillAppear` method, go ahead and assign this value back to the textField.

If necessary use `[tableView reloadData]` if this is used in a tableView or use `[self reloadInputViews]`  (if necessary).

Then again, its all logical. Nothing too complex in code.

Comment: The first chunk of code I posted is actually in the configureCell method because the UITextField is in a UITableViewCell, so should I still do what you said in viewDidLoad, or in this method?

Comment: no. in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, where you initialize textfield.

Comment: I can't do `self.myTextField = textField` because `textField is declared in the `configureCell` method.

Comment: You can if you implement the UITextFieldDelegate and use the method I had pasted.

Comment: I have that method in there. One sec let me give you more code.

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextFieldDelegate method that is textFieldDidEndEditing, which gets called when editing ends

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:

```
NSString *tempRoutineName = self.myTextField.text;
self.routineName = tempRoutineName;
[tempRoutineName release];
```

You haven't own tempRoutineName to release. Comment out the release and check.